# Projects Showcase

Tags: joomla, gallery, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I'm a web developer and I have several small projects (website, software applications, etc) which I'd like to publish it in my site. I was thinking to show it something like a gallery.

It would be exactly [jQuery Labs' layout](http://www.jquerylabs.com/): A thumbnail for preview, the title and then a link to the project profile. Websites like this have its own system to register their projects so that it can be done dynamically (no HTML editing everytime a new project is added) and save time, patience and on.

Because of my site is Joomla based, I'd like to know some extension that does this for me, or at least simulate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at CCK components like http://www.getk2.org or http://www.flexicontent.org/

You get to create all of the fields you need. With flexicontent you can also control privileges using Flexiaccess. Both allow you to create templates for each 'project' which can be populated at the front or backend.

Comment: Great! You hit the bull's eye